# Could not find org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I was trying to learn how to use OkHTTP. I importetd the library to my project but when i compile the code it brings out this error.

Could not find org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:.
Required by:
project :app
Search in build.gradle files.

please what should i do. This is my build.gradle below

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
compileSdk 32

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.omolayoseun.saprktesterapp"
    minSdk 23
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard- 
rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'

}
```

Comment: Try refreshing your project: File : Sync project with Gradle files

Comment: i have tried it .It is showing => Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that your problem is in the maven repository setting.
Place the code below to your ***build.gradle*** which is located in the project core folder.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}}
```

If it not helps or this repositories already there - try to turn off offline mode.
Go to Preferences > Gradle and uncheck "Offline work"
If Gradle is in offline mode, which means that it won't go to the network to resolve dependencies.

Answer (score 15):

**junit-jupiter** dependency is used only for **running junit 5 Unit tests**, in your case you don't even need this dependency. Feel free to **delete it**. And make sure you run the project by selecting **app**[image: run project picture] in  the run menu.

Once you decide to run actual unit tests use these dependencies:

```
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
```

Comment: And choose only one form following testImplementations. Because "junit:JUnit" - it's JUnit4 and "junit-jupiter-api" - it's JUnit5 (newer version of JUnit)

Comment: That helped in my case. Thanks a lot.